# copy data from MSSQL database to Postgresql database with Python

Tags: python, psycopg2, pymssql

I have two 2 databases. One with MSSQL and another with Postgresql.
I want that my python script is running (for this I use a cron-job on linux), every day.
The data from the MSSQL database should copied to the Postgresql database. I have an idea but it doesn't works. Could you help me??? Maybe my solution is totally wrong...

That's my code:

```
import pymssql, psycopg2

class DatabaseRequest:

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn1 = pymssql.connect(host='****', user='****', password='****', database='****')
        self.conn2 = psycopg2.connect("dbname='****' user='****' host='*****' password='****'")

        self.cur1 = self.conn1.cursor()
        self.cur2 = self.conn2.cursor()

    def request_proc(self, rows):
        self.cur1.execute("SELECT top 10  tag, site, plant, unit, line, ProcessID AS pid, Count(ReadTime) AS mods \
                        FROM ( \
                        select dateadd(dd, -1, convert(varchar, getDate(),111)) \
                        as tag, ReadTime, processID, subid, PR.Site, PR.Plant, PR.Unit, PR.Line \
                        from FactBarcodeReading BCR with(nolock) \
                        inner join DimProcess PR on BCR.ProcessKey = PR.ProcessKey \
                        where PR.ProcessID IN  (802, 1190, 1800, 3090, 3590, 4390, 4590, 4800, 5000, 5400, 4190) \
                        and ReadTime between dateadd(dd, -1, convert(varchar, getDate(),111)) and dateadd(dd, -0, convert(varchar, getDate(),111)) \
                        ) a \
                        GROUP BY tag, site, plant, unit, line, ProcessID \
                        ORDER BY site, plant, unit, line, ProcessID")

        rows = self.cur1.fetchone()

       # return rows   


    def insert_proc(self):
        self.cur2.execute("INSERT INTO 20091229global (proddate, site, plant, unit, line, pid, mods) \
                        VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
                        % self.cur1.fetchone())


        a = DatabaseRequest()
        print a.insert_proc()
```

PS: the request_proc works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the code produces no errors but the inserted records are not appearing in the Postgresql database, you most likely need to add `self.conn2.commit()` after executing the INSERT statement.  This will commit each transaction to the database.

According to the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.set_transaction), it is also possible to enable automatic transactions.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to pass the cursor (cur1) into insert_proc -->

```
def insert_proc(self, cur1):
  self.cur2.execute("INSERT INTO 20091229global (proddate, site, plant, unit, line, pid, mods) \
                        VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
                        % self.cur1.fetchone())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just seeing this thread after having tried to find the answer myself. You can use a method from psycopg2.extras called execute_values().

In the documentation https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html you can find it near the bottom. Just pass a single string variable, then define that placeholder as a values list.